# angular route is not working and not changing current view

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a new component with 'ng generate component', but after pressing navigating the url  the target view doesn't load, I don't know why. The url will be changed correctly but the view will be not changed.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Overview';

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  onPressStart($event){    

    this.router.navigate(['/start']);
  }
```

}

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StartComponent } from './start/start.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.mdoules.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StartComponent } from './start/start.component';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [ {path: "", component:AppComponent},  {path: "start", component: StartComponent} ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your js console when you try to change routes?

Comment: yes, there are some errors if the route is not known.

Answer (score 2):

The `AppComponent` and `StartComponent` should not be siblings like you did.
`AppComponent` is bootstrapped, that means it's your root component and you should not try to load it with a route.

So just put a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside `AppComponent` which will act as a placeholder for route-loaded components.

Then remove `AppComponent` from the routes, and all of your routes will work.